# why do we use curly braces while defining constant variable in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, graphql, react-props

i write this following code to fetch the title from props .
Before:

```
export default function Articleinfo(props) {
    const  {edge}  = props.data.allNodeArticle;
    
    return(
        <>
          <div>
              <h1>Title:{edge[0].title}</h1>
              <h2>info:</h2>
          </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

i getting this error : **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')**

But After : When i remove the curly braces it worked

```
export default function Articleinfo(props) {
    const  edge  = props.data.allNodeArticle;
    console.log(edge.nodes[0].title);
    const Title = edge.nodes[0].title;
    return(
        <>
          <div>
              <h1>Title:{edge.nodes[0].title}</h1>
              <h2>info:</h2>
          </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

**Can some explain me why this happen? what is the concept behind it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces are used for Object destructuring

In the link below syntax for object destructing is explained

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

So when you do

```
    const  {edge}  = props.data.allNodeArticle;
```

this means that the object **allNodeArticle** has a key named **edge** and you are accessing it

But when you do the followinng and error goes it means allNodeArticle is not an object having  a key  edge instead it has array nodes  it.

```
const  edge  = props.data.allNodeArticle;
console.log(edge.nodes[0].title);
```